# python list items & convert language codes to names

Tags: python, list

i have a list of languages in my data store for a country which is stored like this :

```
[u"[u'fa-AF'", u" u'ps'", u" u'uz-AF'", u" u'tk']"]
```

i want the output as:

fa-AF, ps, uz-AF, tk

or

fa-AF - ps, uz-AF - tk

i have tried a couple of things but have not succeeded yet. seems like the data that has been imported to the datastore was not imported properly. Any help Regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, i would like your suggestions on how to display the language name with these codes.

for example if we have "en-US" then we would like to display it as English (United States)
(Note: we do not have the language names stored in the datastore.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [u"[u'fa-AF'", u" u'ps'", u" u'uz-AF'", u" u'tk']"]
```

Looks like a simple split of the original string. You can re-build the string or strip individual elements:

```
import ast
codes = [ast.literal_eval(x.strip('[] ')).encode() for x in a]
```

or

```
codes = [elem.encode() for elem in ast.literal_eval(','.join(a))]
```

both return:

```
['fa-AF', 'ps', 'uz-AF', 'tk']
```

The names of the languages could be stored in a dictionary, such as:

```
lang = {'fa-AF': 'farsi-Afghanistan', ... }
```

and called with

```
for code in codes:
    print lang[code]
```

or you can have a look at the [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) library.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response however i still get an error with this:   TypeError: strip arg must be None, unicode or str

Comment: @Amyth - then try the other possibility with rebuilding the string. See my answer.

Comment: that works perfect thanks. Which one you think would be better saving the language names with their codes in a dictionary or using an external library to to convert the codes to names ?

Comment: If you can install the external library, use it (maybe it offers further tools you can use).

Comment: Babel is definitely better than anything homegrown, as it already contains a wide set of translations for language names.

Comment: Thanks all, babel is pretty good! i was able to achieve what i was looking for!